# Switch among windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a bunch of windows forms. Each form has "Back" and "Next" buttons for switching forms. For example, clicking "Back" on Form3 then we go to Form2. Then clicking "Next" button on Form2 then Form3 is shown.

Now my question is that if we click "Next" from the very beginning, it works smoothly. However if I click "Back" on Form3 then Form2 is displayed, then click "Next" on Form3 go to Form3. The code doesn't goto Form3_Load event.
What is wrong in my code?

```
 public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    Form2 FormPrev;
    Form4 FormNext;
    List<DataRow> drlist = new List<DataRow>();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public Form3(Form2 _FormPrev)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormPrev = _FormPrev;
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowNext();
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowPrev();
    }

    private void ShowNext()
    {
        if (FormNext == null)
            FormNext = new Form4(this);
        FormNext.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void ShowPrev()
    {
        FormPrev.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // blah blah.
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A form's Load event is only fired when the form is invoked for the first time.  If you subsequently hide the form and reshow it then this is not reloading the form so the form's Load event is not fired.

If you want to use an event to handle when the form is re-displayed then you should look at the following more suitable events:

Activated
Shown
VisibleChanged

Comment: Shown is also only going to be fired once when it first becomes visible.

Comment: I like this idea. But the form displays twice when first time click. Need code help.

Comment: Assuming the same code as you posted in your question, then you simply replace the Form3_Load method with:

    private void Form3_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Visible)
        {
            // blah blah.
        }
    }

Comment: Got an exception in designer file if remove Load method. this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form3_Load); And code never reach VisibleChanged method if remove Load.

Comment: Open the form's designer, navigate to properties, remove the value for the form's load event.  Add add the relevant  entry to the VisibleChanged event?  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Form Load event only gets fired before the form is shown for the first time.
You should use a different event, like maybe Form Activated or GotFocus.

Answer (score 0):

That's a normal behaviour. Load is for load form, not for show. In your case you try to show hided form. If you want to use

```
form.Show()
```

than use not a

```
form.Hide()
```

but

```
form.Close()
```

**UPD:**
Code should be:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    List<DataRow> drlist = new List<DataRow>();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowNext();
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowPrev();
    }

    private void ShowNext()
    {
        Form4 formNext = new Form4();
        formNext.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void ShowPrev()
    {
        Form2 formPrev = new Form2();
        formPrev.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // blah blah.
    }
}
```

But there is a problem with such colutions - you shouldn't close your main form.

Comment: No, an exception will be thrown becasue I defined Form2 FormPrev; 
    Form4 FormNext; in Form 3.Cannot access a disposed object.

Comment: Yep, that's normal, you should create form again by new Form()

Comment: So I need code for distingushing events by clicking "Next" button. In other words, the first time I click "Next" then Load is fired, but if I back and next again, a new event is fired. How the code is like?

Comment: It doesn't contain a constructor and 0 argument error, let me double check.

Comment: I removed all arguments from constructor, because in such case you don't need them.